# High Voltage Active Rectification using Silicon Carbide MOSFET

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

This is a purely theoretical question, please forgive me if I am being stupid.

Synchronous rectification and secondary side control of DC/DC converters is very commonplace in low voltage, high current applications because the MOSFETs can have lower voltage drops than diodes, meaning efficiency isn't deteriorated during rectification of the AC voltage. In high voltage applications, the DC voltage can sufficiently handle the voltage drops of the diodes without effecting the efficiency significantly since the drops are relatively small. Furthermore, MOSFET ratings mean that they cannot be used in kV range output applications.

Theoretically, now that high voltage rated silicon carbide devices exist such as the 3.3kV CoolMOS, could there possibly be any benefit to using active rectification/synchronous rectification in high voltage, low current applications? Possibly adding extra control in the secondary side may lead to tighter voltage regulation, or the benefits of topologies such as the dual active bridge can be realized in HV applications where the usually wouldn't have been?

Or would it be much better to just stick to silicon carbide Schottky diodes in the HV full bridge rectifier/multiplier, or even just good old silicon devices?

Comment: IGBT's have always had high voltage ratings.  If active rectification was valuable, wouldn't active rectification have been done with IGBT's already?

Comment: @scorpdaddy Very fair point! :) How about secondary side control, though? You could argue the point of IGBT again but the frequency could be much higher with MOSFET.